# How do I display from text file that gets updates every 10 minutes on my html site?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a python script, which updates a text file every 10 minutes. I have a js script which takes the data and uses `innerHTML` to update the page.

I just need to know how to fit everything together so that it all works?

If you need any info, please comment and i'll respond within 5-10 mins.

Comment: Where is your code?  What should it do when "it all works"?

Comment: When it all works, the python code will scrape data and upload it to a textfile every 10 minutes, overriding the previous data, then, the js will display this data on the site.

Comment: Every time you load the html the data will be updated as in txt file but you want to update in live you need to use Ajax

Comment: does that mean I have to use ajax in order to display the data?

Comment: I think Scott Hunter's request is totally reasonable. Could you show us your JavaScript? In the meantime, why not execute the JS every 10 minutes or so, having it go get the text file contents again?

Comment: With Ajax, web applications can send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.